# R programming - FindRoot of equation of the form f(x)=0

Tags: r

I am trying to perform `FindRoot` operation as in Mathematic using `uniroot` in `R` programming. My equation is of the form `f(x)=0`, which I am not able to specify. I got some output, which is continuously changing based on the initial estimate in `uniroot` function. Below is that piece of code. Kindly suggest.

Code is below :

```
sumTc <- 3365955    
 n <- 136    
 tn <- 88682     

fun_b <- function(b){
    c <- 1
    1/b -1/(exp(b*(tn^c))-1) - sumTc/n
 }
uniroot(fun_b, c(-2,1))$root
```

This gives a values of `2.396734e-05`

```
uniroot(fun_b, c(-1,1))$root
```

This gives a value of `9.414755e-05`

Not sure if the way I am solving the equationis correct.

Comment: can   u show your code

Comment: @Thennarasu I am just trying that function to solve the equation I have specified above. I have posted the code here already.

Comment: @VIDHYA SHREE  You have not shown us everything at all. You define a function `fun_b` but want the root of `fun_bMLE`. In addition objects `tn` and `sumTc` and `n` are not defined in your example.

Comment: sumTc <-  3365955, n <- 136, tn <- 88682. These are the values that I had considered for the calculation

Comment: Your example is still not reproducible: you have not provided all missing information. See my previous comment. And edit your original question.

Comment: I have edited the code. Kindly try now

Comment: Where is the function `funb_MLE`?

Comment: I assume that `fun_bMLE` is the same as `fun_b`. Do some experiments with the `tol` argument of function `uniroot`. For example try `tol=.Machine$double.eps^0.75` and you will see that the answers in both cases are very close. Just read the help for `uniroot`.